# How to ensure screenshot from Bing Aerial matches QGIS Bing Satellite?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, bing-maps

I am looking to work from a screenshot of Bing Aerial that is georeferenced in relation to Bing Satellite from the QuickMapServices plugin in QGIS 3.4.3.

I have matched the scale from the Bing Aerial image in QGIS and, as far as I am aware, both maps should otherwise be identical.

However (please see attachment), Bing Aerial and Bing Satellite do not align (without further adjustment of the image). Why might this be?

[image: Example of image overlay]

Answer (score 1):

All satellite imagery and aerial imagery will have a certain level of misalignment down to how well it was orthorectified.

If you want the two to match up you can georeference the aerial imagery using the satellite imagery you want it to match.

Comment: Thanks Heikki. Assuming there is no better way of streamlining this process?

Comment: Buy some already orthorectified aerial imagery.